# SQLite database file was locked

Tags: sqlite

I am getting the error as `SQLITE database file was locked` when I tried to open the connection multiple times this is what I have written

```
if (m_oDataSet2.Tables["401k"].Rows.Count != 0)
{
    double maxlimit;
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + path + ""))
    {
      conn.Open();   
    }
 }
```

On first hit it is executing fine when it is looping for the second time I am getting this error how to resolve this

Comment: What library does the SQLiteConnection type belong to? Where did you get that library?

Comment: It is from the application folder `myapplication/DB/db.db`

Comment: If you have the definition of this type, can you post it?

Comment: Did you write `SQLiteConnection` yourself? If yes, can you post its definition (the source code)? If you are using some already compile library, where does this library come from?

Comment: I posted that na my sqlconnection will get from the application folder as mentioned `myapplication/DB/db.db`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try closing the connection each time after you're finished with it. Or, just open it once on program startup and retain the connection throughout your app's lifetime.

Comment: I think `using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + path + ""))` will automatically close the connection right

Comment: Presumably, but why would you make this assumption unless you know for a fact that the finalizer of SQLiteConnection does close the connection?

Answer (score -1):

Just insert conn.close(); before catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)